# Database design for an auction style website

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm creating an auction style website where users can bid for items. I've into a bit of confusion regarding the database design when it comes down to projects and bidding features. Initially I thought a table called 'project' could contain a multiple-valued column called 'bids' containing bid_id's.. However after a bit of research it appears this method is a no-no.. But I'm sure I can remember a lecture or two from university that mentioned multi-valued columns in database designs. What would be the best approach for the problem?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: You shouldn't initially think of a table. That's how programming was done in the 1980s. :) [You should initially think of value for your users.](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html)

Comment: It's unfortunate that universities still teach this outdated method then? But I did like your link! Doesn't help answer the question but thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your requirements on how to design the database. If you have exactly one auction per product ID, a `BID` table may be enough. If each auction requires individual configurations you may end up with an `AUCTION` table as well:

**The product table**

```
PRODUCT
 PRODUCT_ID    -- primary key
 ....
```

**Auction table**

```
AUCTION
 AUCTION_ID    -- PK
 PRODUCT_ID    -- foreign key to PRODUCT
 START_TIME
 END_TIME
 MODE          -- e.g. dutch, english...
 ...
```

**Bid table**

```
BID
 BID_ID        -- PK
 AUCTION_ID    -- foreign key to AUCTION
 AMOUNT
 TIME
 ...
```

In general, you should avoid multi-valued columns in a relational database model. You should aim for [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If it later comes to query optimization you may need to introduce further indexes, views and/or procedures.

Comment: how about auction table , with column status? "item sold, action cancelled", and a also another column for most recent auction winning bid?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution would be to have a table `bids` containing all the necessary information in columns, for example: `bid_id`, `product_id`, `bid_amount`, `bid_time`, etc.

Comment: There is an existing table called bids that contains bid_id, product_id, bidder_id etc... However this was drawn up by another developer, and I was just wondering if this was the best way to do it as some of his other 'code' is very questionable. So doing it this way would require you to search all entries in 'bids' for entries that match a given 'product_id'?

Comment: @Dan, No need to search in a relational database. There will be a *real* relation between the products and the bids.

Answer (score 0):

this is only meta-sql, you know.

users: id, ...
bids: id, auction_id, user_id, amount, 
auctions: id, object, ... end-date, ...

indexes on bids: auction_id, amount desc
(among others like id's, names ...)